# Is saying "the sequence converges" the same as saying "the sequence has a limit"?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, cauchy-sequences

I'm reading a book on set theory and it has some real analyisis in it, and since i've only studied analysis in college and i didn't understand much honestly now studying by myself i'm struggling a little on some concepts. Is saying "the sequence converges" the same as saying "the sequence has a limit" or there is a difference?

Thank you!

Comment: These two statements are usually exact synonyms

Comment: It would help if you tell us the name of the book as well.

Comment: @AsafKaragila classic set theory for guided independent study